# Нужны ли здесь еще запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

Отметим наступающие праздники на заводе по традиции — всем коллективом, в нашем почти «семейном» арматурном кругу.

Answer (score 2):

На заводе отметим наступающие праздники  по традиции  всем коллективом, в нашем почти семейном "арматурном" кругу.

В Вашем предложении желательно разбавить ряд обстоятельств, переставив одно из них ближе к началу. Кавычками можно выделить слово АРМАТУРНЫЙ, так как оно употреблено в необычном значении. Допустимо оформление запятыми ПОЧТИ СЕМЕЙНОМ для выделения смысла.

Comment: Екатерина, вы правы. Но в первом предложении должна стоять запятая после " семейном".

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: Отметим наступающие праздники на заводе по традиции — всем коллективом, в нашем почти семейном, арматурном кругу. Или: Отметим наступающие праздники на заводе по традиции — всем коллективом, в нашем почти семейно-арматурном кругу.  Определение "почти" должно относиться к ближайшему прилагательному, а не отделяться запятой от него. Здесь нет уточнения.